# Is there a way to use an input value (textbox) of a userform as a variable for another userform?

Tags: vba, variables, textbox

Ok so what I am trying to accomplish: I have one userform that asks how many new orders the user needs to process. I set the user input to a variable in this code (not sure if it even does anything).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm2.Show
    OrderNum.Text = NewOrders
'I changed the textbox name to OrderNum

End Sub
```

Then when UserForm2 pops up, I want to be able to input more data with more specific information about the orders. So if on Userform1 I entered in 3, I want to have to submit new data into UserForm2 3 different times. I tried using a For - Next loop (below) but it doesn't work. I'm not sure how (or if) I can store variables like that between Userforms.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Core Info")
OrderNum.Text = NewOrders
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

For i = 1 To NewOrders

ws.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
ws.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = TextBox2.Text

Next i

UserForm2.Hide

End Sub
```

The the second userform pops up as it should, but then nothing works after that. Can anyone tell me what I could do to fix this?

Note: I realize that those of the above start with CommandButton1 (default) but they are on different Userforms.

Comment: To submit data 3 different times, you are going to need 3 form controls (e.g., `textbox`, etc.) or you are going to need to display the form 3 separate times.  Aside from that, it is not entirely clear what you are asking -- I understand what I think you are trying to do, but the description and the code you have provided is not enough to really help you. You have only posted the code for 1 event and that does not give enough detail about how/when the separate forms are displayed, etc. Please consider adding more code or a more detailed description of the process.

Comment: @DavidZemens I guess I didn't realize I was being unclear. As for the process: When the first userform pops up and asks "How many New orders do you have", I want to be able to say however many there are for that day, then click submit. Then once I click submit, I want that next userform to take my data, export it into the next available row in a column, then come back and ask for my data again, and again, until it has gone the number of times I specified in the first userform. Does that explain the process any better? As for more/better code, that's why I am here unfortunately...

Comment: Why do you need a second user form to submit the data to the worksheet? If you have already captured the information in `UserForm1`, why don't you just have that form submit the data to the worksheet?

Comment: The first userform only asks how many new entries I will need to make. Userform2 is where I will enter multiple data points specific to each entry. So for example if I have 2 new orders, I specify that on Userform1, click submit. On Userform2 I specify that the first is a shirt and the color is blue, then click submit and it puts that information in the designated cells. Then it pops up again and i specify that the order is for shoes that are black, click submit, puts info in next cell, and the sub is over because i only specified 2 orders that time.

Comment: OK. I still think one form might be easier to use, but if you want to use 2 forms there are several ways you can do this. Easiest will be to use a public variable. I will suggest another method though.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful (and is good coding practice) to give your form controls more easily recognizable names, instead of the ambiguous `CommandButton1` nomenclature. Revise `CommandButton1`'s name on `UserForm1` to `Form1_SubmitButton`.  Then, use this code to handle the form submission.

```
Sub Form1_SubmitButton_Click()
' a textbox control named OrderNum on UserForm1 has captured the value
'Assign the value from the OrderNum textbox to a named variable in the worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "OrderNum", Me.OrderNum.Text

UserForm2.Show


End Sub
```

Then, in UserForm2 change the name of your command button to something like `Form2_SubmitButton` and use this code:

```
Sub Form2_SubmitButton_Click()
Dim orderNum as Long
orderNum = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Names("OrderNum").Value,"=",vbNullString)

'the rest of your code goes here.

End Sub
```

So, what we have done above is to create a `Name` in the worksheet which contains the value you want to use on the several forms.  You can always obtain this value by `Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Names("OrderNum").Value,"=",vbNullString)`

Alternatively, you could use a public variable in your code module.

Comment: David, I have done all of that, but instead of Userform2 popping back up to allow me to fill out more data x more times. Userform1 pops up again instead and they just go back and forth when i hit each of their respective submit buttons. It will not repeat userform2 for the amount of times specified in userform1.

Comment: Your question asked how to pass variables between user forms. I provided information on how to do this. If this answer resolves that specific problem, please mark the answer as "accepted". If you have additional questions or problems (it seems like you do not understand how to work with loops), please ask them as *new questions*.